# how to add space between items in listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

The below mentioned layout is a model of one item in a `ListView`. As you see it, the three TextViews are separated from each as each one occupies `.3` of the entire row space.

The problem is, when I add items to the `ListView` I found that the three `TextView`s are just linked to each other. For example, let's assume I want to add item to the `ListView` contains the following:

```
Adam USA M
```

I expect to see that row on the screen with some spaces separating each textView, but what happens is that I get something like the following:

```
AdamUSAM
```

Why this is happening and how to solve it?

**model_view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:text="Name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:text="Address: "/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:text="gender: "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**:

Now I changed the layout to be as follows, but the problem is persists which is that the three textviews are appearing clinching to each other without spacing.

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="gender: "
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**screen shot**:

[image]

Comment: can u share a screenshot?

Comment: @Enzokie screen shot added

Comment: As far as `xml` goes the layout is okay, are you sure you're inflating the right layout file?

Comment: Can you guarantee that your LinearLayout is really getting the device width? It seems that the issue is caused by the listview itself.

Comment: @Pztar yes i am sure

Comment: @Enzokie i could not understand what you mean

Comment: Is your `ListView` width set to `wrap_content`? It should be `match_parent`

Comment: I tested the code above and it is working as expected http://imgur.com/a/mRojz the only thing I add is gravity but that doesnt matter.

Comment: @Pztar you spotted it right..it was due to the width of the listview was set to wrap_content

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the orientation of `LinearLayout` e.g. `android:orientation="horizontal"` then replace your weights to 1 instead of 0.3 and make sure your `TextView` width is `0dp` not `wrap_content`.

Comment: This is the correct answer except `layout_weight` does not need to be 1 it can be anything that has equal weights as long as the total sum of the weights does not exceed `weightSum` (which has not been specified)

Comment: please see my updated layout..i did as u suggested but still the problem perisists

Comment: @user2121 pls add a screenshot so that we can look

Comment: @Enzokie screen shot added

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`layout_margin`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) or [`padding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getPaddingLeft()) to each `TextView`.

Comment: but why that is happening despite there is a weight specified for each TextView?

Comment: @user2121 because you've set the `layout_width` to be `wrap_content` if you set it to `0dp` and also set your root layout to have `android:orientation="horizontal"` you'll have your desired look

Answer (score 0):

Use property
     android:layout_margin="10dp"

Comment: but why that is happening despite there is a weight specified for each TextView?

Comment: Try using weight instead of layout_weight. Also, try specifying width as match_parent. Use these combinations. I am not sure why your text views are behaving like this but maybe it's because of the combinations of width.

Answer (score 0):

in your listView xml add :

```
android:dividerHeight="8 dip"
```

or any value you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove `layout_weight` from `TextViews`, define a specific `height` to them and add padding. Adding margins may cause your `TextViews` to go out of `ListView`.